# Anomalic popup and other ads in Mozilla Firefox after plugin instal

Tags: firefox, search

I have some questions about newest Mozilla Firefox:

1. Recently I installed the newest Mozilla Firefox, where the default search engine was Google. One day I realized that the search engine is Eazel and I can't change it. In the settings I set a different default engine but nothing has changed.
2. Since the default searcher is Eazel I get a several of adverts (popping windows for example). After I installed the Adblock Plus, the frame of the ads are still there, it just doesn't show anything. The popping windows are still there too, but after they appear they suddenly disappear too. I installed some plugins and I think those cause these troubles.

[image: The problematic ads]

Comment: If you get infected with malware that changes your search provider to something you don't want it to be. You can either remove the malware or what works most of the time is to delete the Firefox profile entire.  Of course I don't see an actual question

Comment: @blackcornail: See this guide for removing it: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/eazel-search-removal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been hit by malware. Install MalwareBytes' Anti-Malware and let it run a scan.

www.malwarebytes.org

Comment: also, i'm not judging, but the word is 'anomalous'.